# Apply the Riemann Map Theorem and Schwartz's Lemma.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Let $U$ be an open and simply connected of $\mathbf{C}$ such that $0 \in U \neq \mathbf{C}$ and $U$ is symmetric about zero(that is, $z \in U \Leftrightarrow-z \in U$ ).

a) If $f: D \rightarrow U$ is a biholomorphism such that $f(0)=0$. Prove that $f(-z)=$ $-f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

b) Give an example of a holomorphic function $f: \mathbf{D} \longmapsto \mathbf{C}$ such that it is surjective.

Comment: I see you mentioned the Riemann mapping theorem and Schwarz's lemma in the title. Could you please your thoughts about applying these theorems? Where precisely are you stuck?

Comment: RMT has a unicity part fixing a point and the argument of the derivative there; if you take $g(z)=-f(-z)$ for the given $f$ what happens with those at $z=0$?; for the second part it may be easier to construct a surjective holomorphic map from a half-plane to the full plane (even a very simple polynomial may work in this case)